# How to print the given strings with respect to the % integer value obtained (0-100)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm

TXT_0 = "◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_1 = "⬛️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_2 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_3 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_4 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_5 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_6 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_7 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ◻️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_8 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ◻️ ◻️"

TXT_9 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ◻️"

TXT_10 = "⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️ ⬛️"

'x' is a real-time integer variable from a percentage calculation function.

Eg:

```
if x < 10:
  print(TXT_0)

if (x >= 10) and (x < 20):

  print(TXT_1)
```

I want to print the above text like a percentage display!
Need to print the corresponding string with respect to the input between 0 - 100!

Comment: You already answered yourself with the two `if`s. If you need to do it in a loop, just use `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really painful way to do it. Instead, just generate the output string you want based on a calculation.

```py
print (x//10 * "⬛️ " + (10-x//10) * "◻️ ")
```

If for some reason you have a genuine need to keep all the strings in memory, probably keep them in an array.

```py
indicator = [i*"⬛️ " + (10-i)*"◻️ " for i in range(11)]
```

Notice that Python's arrays are zero-based; the one corresponding to zero to nine per cent is `indicator[0]` and the one to one hundred per cent is `indicator[10]`.